# Change the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 white dial pad to another color

Tags: phone-app, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I just got a black Galaxy Note 3 from an att store with my upgrade. I saw that the phone dial pad was white when I got it, but I thought I could change it later. WRONG!

I have been on lots of Android websites but can't find an answer. I am already an Android central member where I get most of the answers to my Android questions. There are a lot of people with the same issue.

It looks like the US got the white keypad and background and Canada got black on black. This is way too bright for me. I have eye issues. I know I can use a third party app if I have to. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try a different dialer like [GO Contacts Ex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbapps.contactpro&hl=en), and have it replace the stock dialer. It lets you change themes / colors.